# How to know which header column is right clicked in a ListView?

Tags: c#, listview

I found a way to handler right click in a `ListView Header` column.

I needed to define a new `ListView` item and override `WndProc`.

```
public class ListViewUpdated : ListView
{
    public ContextMenuStrip HeaderContextMenu { get; set; }
    private frmMain mainForm;


    public ListViewUpdated()
    {
        mainForm = null;
    }

    public void setAttributes(frmMain frm, ContextMenuStrip menu)
    {
        mainForm = frm;
        HeaderContextMenu = menu;
    }

    protected override void WndProc(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m)
    {
        base.WndProc(ref m);
        if (m.Msg == 0x7b)
        {  //WM_CONTEXTMENU
            if (m.WParam != this.Handle)
            {
                mainForm.Invoke(mainForm.delegateDeleteColumn,
                                  new Object[] { HeaderContextMenu });
            }
        }
    }

    private void InitializeComponent()
    {
        this.SuspendLayout();
        this.ResumeLayout(false);

    }
}
```

This does work fine. I used a delegate so the event trigger could be a function within the form.

The event so far within the form is this:

```
    if (tabControl1.SelectedIndex == 0)
    {
        System.Drawing.Point mousePos = lsvRequestsByParameters.PointToClient(Control.MousePosition);
        hitTest = lsvRequestsByParameters.HitTest(mousePos);
    }
    else
    {
        System.Drawing.Point mousePos = lsvRequestsByParametersToSave.PointToClient(Control.MousePosition);
        hitTest = lsvRequestsByParametersToSave.HitTest(mousePos);
    }
    HeaderContextMenu.Show(Control.MousePosition);
```

It is called properly.

It does allow me to popup the context menu on the header.

The problem is one of the option is delete column:

```
private void deleteColumnToolStripMenuItem2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int columnIndex = hitTest.Item.SubItems.IndexOf(hitTest.SubItem);
    lsvRequestsByParameters.Columns.RemoveAt(columnIndex);
}
```

Problem is the following line:

```
int columnIndex = hitTest.Item.SubItems.IndexOf(hitTest.SubItem);
```

It seems that when I set the `hitTest` variable, if the mouse is over a header, it doesn't return a content usable. Note that using hitTest this way would return me the `columnIndex` properly if I click on a empty cell.

So what can I do instead to obtain the `columnIndex`?

Comment: do you really need right click a column header? why not remove this requirement to make it simple?

Comment: requirement for a projet, cannot go without it. I'm having a hard time believing that this stupid thing turn out to be so complex...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as there are `Items` in the `ListView` you could **fool** the `HitTest` by feeding in a location that is **below** the header..:

```
Point eLoc = listView1.PointToClient(Control.MousePosition);
ListViewHitTestInfo hit = null;
int i = 0;
do
{
    Point vp = new Point(eLoc.X, listView1.Items[i].Bounds.Top);
    hit = listView1.HitTest(vp);
    i++;
}
while( hit.SubItem == null && i < listView1.Items.Count);
var ColumnIndex = hit.Item.SubItems.IndexOf(hit.SubItem);
```

Note that the loop is only necessary if your `SubItems` are jagged. Otherwise you can simply always go for `Items[0]`.

---

**Update:**

If for reason you want to allow clicking the headers of an **empty** `ListView`, you can use this workaround:

Declare a variable that holds all the bounding rectangles of the headers:

```
 private List<Rectangle> lvHeaderBounds = new List<Rectangle>();
```

In the above code that processes the `ColumnClick` use this:

```
 Point eLoc = listView1.PointToClient(Control.MousePosition);
 var ColumnIndex = -1;
 if (listView1.Items.Count == 0)
 {
      getHeaders(listView1);
      for (int i = 0; i < lvHeaderBounds.Count; i++)
           if (lvHeaderBounds[i].X + lvHeaderBounds[i].Width > eLoc.X)
           {
                ColumnIndex =  i;
                break;
           }
 }
 else...
```

To collect the bounding rectangles we need to loop over the `ColumHeader` collection. Here is a function that achieves this:

```
void getHeaders(ListView lv)
{
    lvHeaderBounds.Clear();
    for (int i = 0; i < lv.Columns.Count; i++)
    {
        ColumnHeader ch = lv.Columns[i];
        int left = i == 0 ? 0 : lvHeaderBounds[i-1].X + ch.Width;
        Rectangle r = new Rectangle(left, 0, ch.Width, 0);
        lvHeaderBounds.Add(r);
    }
}
```

We also need to **refresh** our collection when the user or code modifies the header layout:

```
    private void listView1_ColumnReordered(object sender, ColumnReorderedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (lvHeaderBounds != null) lvHeaderBounds.Clear();
        getHeaders(sender as ListView);
    }

    private void listView1_ColumnWidthChanged(object sender, ColumnWidthChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (lvHeaderBounds != null) lvHeaderBounds.Clear();
        getHeaders(sender as ListView);
    }
```

Note that the `Height` values in our list are all `0`!

Also note that in my tests the code works even after **resizing** the headers and/or **scrolling** them to the right..

Comment: thanks I tried to fool it that way, however if there is no item in list yet it crashes... :(

Comment: Indeed. For that case you would have to either add a dummy item(+subitems) or in some way measure the column widths. you can do that in the DrawItem event, by making the lv ownerdrawn temporarily...

Comment: thanks!! I marked as anser. I had to do it. SPecifying it in the answer would be a good idea ;)

Comment: Please see my update; the method for treating an empty LV now works without any dummy drawing, DoEvents or other hacksetc..